# How to get background color for a div from option list items background color

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem. You can find codes here:
http://jsfiddle.net/iCannot/ux8uv5v0/3/

```
enter code here
```

As you can see there are some color schemes. When I click one of them, the colors apply as background colors of both of primary and secondary option list items. This part works fine.

When I select a color as primary, that color should fill the box, which is next to the list. But it doesn't. When I select a color as secondary, it works. Then if I select a primary color, whatever I choose, fill the box with very same color of secondary one.

Can someone help me please? Sorry my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery selectors are not accurate enough. The anonymous functions inside the change events should be:

```
$("select#colorList1 option:selected").each(function (){...
...
$("select#colorList2 option:selected").each(function (){...
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ux8uv5v0/5/).